# Prophet model predicts negative values

Tags: python, facebook, time-series, predict, facebook-prophet

I am new to prophet (and stackoverflow in general ;) ) and have some issues with creating a predictive model using python. I am trying to predict daily sales of a product, using around 5 years of data. The data looks as follows: [General data plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cax67.png).

The company is closed in the weekends en during holidays, so there will be no orders. I accounted for this by creating a dataframe with al the weekends/holidays and using this dataframe as an argument for the holidays parameter. Furthermore I didn't change anything from the model, so it looks like: Prophet(holidays = my weekend/holiday dataframe).

However, my model doens't seem to work right and predicts negative values, see the following plot: [Predicition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov8Xy.png). Hereby also the different component plots as extra information: [trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaXSE.png), [holidays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBPU6.png), [weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owE7d.png), [yearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJfD.png). I also tried to just replace the negative values in the prediction by 0, which gives some better result (see [prediction 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD0bV.png)), but I don't think this is the right way to tackle this problem. The last thing I tried was to remove all the weekends from the training and predicting data. The results weren't good either: [prediction 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7ezM.png).

I would love to hear some tips from you guys, for things I could try to do. If anything is unclear or you need more information, just let me know. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score -2):

My suggestions:

1. Try normalization
2. If that doesn't work try using Recurrent Neural Networks